# Can SharePoint Online automatically pull/update from a git repository?

Tags: git, github, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'd like to mirror files from a git repository into SharePoint Online (or Teams) where people could browse through and view/download/share the latest versions of the files without having to download a git client or learn a web interface like github. The copy in SharePoint would be read-only so there weren't conflicts.

Comment: Instead of having SharePoint pull from a GitHub repository, you might use GitHub Actions or another CI system to upload built versions to SharePoint instead.  That's what people usually do with things like websites.

Comment: Oh nice, I will look into that. Thank you @bk2204!

Comment: @Abby Fichtner, Are you still facing the issue.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I am, yes. Although I admittedly haven't had a chance to make much progress on it the past few days. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Does this GitHub action for publishing to Sharepoint help (e.g. when publishing to "Shared Documents")? https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-to-sharepoint